# Vectorize this for loop to compare all possible combinations faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `data_file` with `88k rows`

First five rows of `data_file`

```
data_file[:5]
Out[8]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9  col_10  \
0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10   
1     31     32     33      0      0      0      0      0      0       0   
2     34     35     36      0      0      0      0      0      0       0   
3     37     38     39     40     41     42     43     44     45      46   
4     39     40     48     49      0      0      0      0      0       0   

   col_67  col_68  col_69  col_70  col_71  col_72  col_73  col_74  \
0   ...         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1   ...         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
2   ...         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
3   ...         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
4   ...         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   

   col_75  col_76  
0       0       0  
1       0       0  
2       0       0  
3       0       0  
4       0       0
```

The `data_file` has `88k` rows and `76` columns, Each row can take values between `(0-1000)`, mostly `0's`. This matrix represents `88k` transactions and each transaction/ row represents the items bought.

```
Ex: `2nd-transaction` has items 31,32,33 items amongst 1000 total possible items

 `3rd-transaction` has 34,35,36 items ..and so on..
```

Now to compute `freq_oneItemSet`, we count the number of occurrences of all (1000) items in each `transaction/row`. Then consider the ones greater than `supp_count`. So it is simple:

```
#%%  Compute support count
supp_thresh = 0.02; T_IDS = len(data_file); 
supp_count = math.floor(supp_thresh*T_IDS); 
print("\n Supp_Thresh: ", supp_thresh,
      ";  T_ID's: ", T_IDS, ";  Supp_count: ", supp_count)              
#%% Get frequent one_itemset
print('---Frequent one-ItemSet Generation---')
allUniq_items, allitem_counts = np.unique(data_file, return_counts=True)
allUniq_items = np.delete(allUniq_items,0) # remove added 0's
allitem_counts = np.delete(allitem_counts,0) # remove added 0's
freq_oneItemSet = allUniq_items[allitem_counts >= supp_count]
```

Output: Frequent_oneItemSet, support count and other details:

```
Support-Count:  1763
Number of frequent one-items:  20
Frequent one itemset, Frequent one itemcounts:
[[   33 15167]
 [   37  2936]
 [   39 15596]
 [   40 50675]
 [   42 14945]
 [   49 42135]
 [   66  4472]
 [   90  3837]
 [  102  2237]
 [  111  2794]
 [  148  1779]
 [  171  3099]
 [  226  3257]
 [  238  3032]
 [  272  2094]
 [  311  2594]
 [  414  1880]
 [  439  1863]
 [  476  2167]
 [ 1328  1786]]
------------------------------------
```

Now to generate two-candidates, I see all possible `2-combinations` of `freq_oneItemSet` to check in each row of the main data_file and count occurrences and save if the count of that combination is greater than `supp_count`

Example:

For `2-combination`-[33,39] of `freq_oneItemSet`, we count the number of `rows (88K)` , which have both these items `[33,39]` and so on for all possible combinations and consider than combinations which are greater than `supp_count`.

```
 `[33,39] occurred in 2833 rows`,
 `[33,40] occurred in 8455 rows`
```

My below code output:

```
---Frequent two-candidate Generation---
------------------------------------
---Frequent two-ItemSet---
Support-Count:  1763
Number of frequent two-items:  22
freq_two-ItemSet, freq_two-ItemCount
[[   33    39  2833]
 [   33    40  8455]
 [   33    42  3196]
 [   33    49  8034]
 [   37    39  2790]
 [   37    40  2037]
 [   39    40 10345]
 [   39    42  3897]
 [   39    49  7944]
 [   39   111  2725]
 [   39   171  3031]
 [   40    42 11414]
 [   40    49 29142]
 [   40    66  2787]
 [   40    90  2749]
 [   40   171  2059]
 [   40   226  2351]
 [   40   238  1929]
 [   40   311  1852]
 [   42    49  9018]
 [   49    66  2529]
 [   49    90  2798]]
------------------------------------
```

I have written this code which generates this 190 combinations and checks if it is greater than support count if so appends it to the frequent-two itemset.

It takes 32 seconds for execution can I improve this time?

```
import progressbar
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()    
#%% Generate two-candidate itemsets
print('---Frequent two-candidate Generation---')
freq_twoItemSet = []
freq_twoItemCount = []
ilist = list(itertools.combinations(freq_oneItemSet, 2))
bar_len = len(ilist)
for subset in bar(itertools.combinations(freq_oneItemSet, 2),bar_len):
    #print(subset)
    item_count = np.sum((data_file==subset[0]).any(axis=1) & 
                 (data_file==subset[1]).any(axis=1))
    #item_count = nItem_Count(data_file, subset)
    #print('Total occurences of subset: ', subset, '= ', item_count)
    if item_count >= supp_count:
        freq_twoItemSet.append(subset)
        freq_twoItemCount.append(item_count)
freq_twoItemSet = np.reshape(freq_twoItemSet, (len(freq_twoItemSet),2))
print('------------------------------------')
print('---Frequent two-ItemSet---')
print('Support-Count: ', supp_count)
print('Number of frequent two-items: ', len(freq_twoItemSet))
print('freq_two-ItemSet, freq_two-ItemCount')
print(np.column_stack((freq_twoItemSet, freq_twoItemCount)))
print('------------------------------------')
```

Comment: `ilist = list(itertools.combinations(freq_oneItemSet, 2))` is a huge waste. You can just compute `scipy.misc.comb(len(freq_oneItemSet), 2)`

Comment: Also, what is progressbar? It probably takes up a lot of time...

Comment: Show some sample inputs (including `supp_count`) so I can run this too to reproduce your problem.

Comment: ok, I used it for just progress bar I removed to save some memory. Any suggestions on making it faster. Even if i remove that `bar` in for loop the execution time is still same

Comment: So, here from frequent one items, we see that their count is greater than `supp_count=  1763`. Similarly, we generate `two frequent items` for all combinations greater than `supp_count`

Comment: What type is data_file? Please provide a runnable example...

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to achieve. It seems that neither I nor the other person trying to help you can figure it out. Include the code for the one time repeats and explain what exactly your code is supposed to be doing in words. Please do not respond in a comment. Edit your question to make it complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set approach seems more efficient here, since your matrix looks very sparse.

First computes the sets :

```
frequents=set(freq_oneItemSet) 
sets = [set(row)&frequents for _,row in data_file.iterrows()]
```

Now the pairs :

```
c=collections.Counter()
for s in sets :
    for pair in itertools.combinations(s,2):
        c[pair]+=1
```

I hope this will generate very few traffic, since sets will be thin.

On this (not sparse) exemple :

```
data_file=pd.DataFrame(randint(0,1000,(88000,76)))
frequents=set(range(20))
```

It takes 5 seconds on my computer.

But the pure vectored is still better on this exemple:

```
def g(data_file,frequents):       
    is_in=np.equal.outer(frequents,data_file).any(axis=2)
    first,second,_=np.where(np.logical_and(is_in[:,None],is_in[None]))  
    cp,counts= np.unique(first+1j*second,return_counts=True)
    xp , yp = cp.real.astype(int),cp.imag.astype(int)
    list_ = [((frequents[x],frequents[y]),count) \
    for (x,y,count) in zip(xp,yp,counts) if x<y ]
    return  list_
```

I use complex to simplify the count. In your program you calculate `is_in` ... about 40 times:

```
In [511]: %time s=g(data_file,sorted(np.random.choice(range(1000),20)))
Wall time: 483 ms

In [512]: len(s)
Out[512]: 190
```

Comment: I tried both your codes none gives me expected results. In the first example: sets are generated on all possible length I think, I need only two length sets for all combinations of `freq_oneItemSet`. 20c2 = `190 combinations` possible. In second example: what is `a`, I am getting `20_by_88162` array How is it computed?

Comment: Maybe I will explain my question clearly, From the main `data_file`, we generate `freq_oneItemSet`, which counts the number of occurrences all unique elements in `data_file`, `row_wise`. Then to generate `two_ItemSet`, we repeat the same process along `rows`, but now with all possible `2 set combinations` of `freq_oneItemSet`. For `20` `freq_oneItemSet` we have `20c2 = 190` possible combinations to check in each row of `data_file`. My code does this checking for `190` times making it slow and takes about 32 secs

Comment: Thank you very much, Very neatly, written and it works

Comment: Can we generalize this function for getting `n- candidates`, given `n-1 candidates`? As of now we are doing `2 candidates` given `1- candidates`